# I am trying to change the color of some buttons on a fixed bar menu but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, colors, uinavigationbar

It doesn't matter what color I choose it always remain the same:similar to a link but a darker blue .. here's my code:

```
<!-- Create navigation bar-->
        <style>
            #TopBar{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:40px;
   background-color:#181818;
}
            </style>         
            <div id="TopBar"></div>     
        <!-- Create Page Links -->
        <ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Cos'è</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">Chi Siamo</a></li>
</ul>
        <style>
        ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white; 
    position: absolute;  
    font-size: 20px;        
}
        </style>
<style>
        li {
    display: inline;
}
        </style>
```

I hope someone can help me soon changing the color of the buttons

Comment: any jsfiddle? and you want to change the color of link(a) or buttons?

Comment: if i solved your issue then please mark my answer as final answer..Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the css of a. Please add this in  your code

```
a{color:green;}
```

you can change color from green to whatever you want.

Comment: wow..some frustrated person is giving negative marks to all my answer even if they are right..great..

Answer (score 0):

You could either solve this using `inline CSS`, like this:

```
<li><a style="color: #00ff00;" href="default.asp">Cos'è</a></li>
```

or:

Using the above method you would have to apply it to every single `a` element, that's why using this solution is better:

```
li a {
color: #00ff00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have applied red color to the link.

```
li a{
    color:red;
  }
```

http://jsbin.com/kaduqoharu/2/

Answer (score -1):

More information would be helpful.

If you want different background colors on each menu button, add the "style" and "background-color" code in the tag.  For example:

```
  <li><a style="background-color:red;" href="news.asp">Chi Siamo</a></li>
```

EDIT:

Or if you're trying to change the color of the text, you can add this to each  tags if you're going to use different colors for each of them.

```
      <li><a style="color:red;" href="news.asp">Chi Siamo</a</li>
```

Hoped this helped!